# Syntax error while using subquery

Tags: mysql

Below is my sql query

```
SELECT parts.product_code AS PC,SUM( x.goods_qty ) AS Qty, SUM( x.price * x.goods_qty ) / SUM( x.goods_qty ) AS Avg_Cost, parts.cost_price AS Avg_Cost1, parts.cost_price * parts.bulk_qty AS Total_Cost_Price1, SUM( x.price * x.goods_qty ) / SUM( x.goods_qty ) * parts.bulk_qty AS Total_Cost_Price, parts.sales_price * parts.bulk_qty AS Total_Sales_Price
FROM parts
LEFT JOIN received_goods_details x ON x.part_id = parts.id
LEFT JOIN invoice_details ON invoice_details.part_id = parts.id
WHERE parts.bulk_qty >0

AND
id IN

(SELECT * 
FROM  `received_goods_details` 
WHERE part_id = parts.id
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 5)


GROUP BY parts.id
LIMIT 0 , 30

I am getting a error  #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

i edited my sql query a little bit, removed one where clause

i tried like this but it didn't work too. Here i tried using subquery inside the select statement itself.

```
SELECT parts.product_code AS PC, parts.part_no AS PO, parts.id AS part_id, parts.part_name AS Part_Name, parts.bulk_qty AS Stock, parts.cost_price AS LPP, parts.sales_price AS Sales_Price, SUM( x.goods_qty ) AS Qty, SUM( x.price * x.goods_qty ) / SUM( x.goods_qty ) AS Avg_Cost, parts.cost_price AS Avg_Cost1 FROM ( SELECT *
FROM received_goods_details 
WHERE  part_id = 8
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 5 ) ,

parts.cost_price * parts.bulk_qty AS Total_Cost_Price1, SUM( x.price * x.goods_qty ) / SUM( x.goods_qty ) * parts.bulk_qty AS Total_Cost_Price, parts.sales_price * parts.bulk_qty AS Total_Sales_Price
FROM parts
LEFT JOIN received_goods_details x ON x.part_id = parts.id
LEFT JOIN invoice_details ON invoice_details.part_id = parts.id
WHERE parts.bulk_qty >0
GROUP BY parts.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

now i am getting an error if

SELECT parts.product_code AS PC, parts.part_no AS PO, parts.id AS part_id, parts.part_name AS Part_Name, parts.bulk_qty AS Stock, parts.cost_price AS LPP, parts.sales_price AS Sales_Price, SUM( x.goods_qty ) AS Qty, SUM( x.price * x.goods_qty ) / SUM( x.goods_qty ) AS Avg_Cost, parts.cost_price AS Avg_Cost1 FROM ( SELECT *
FROM received_goods_details
WHERE  y.part_id = parts.id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5 ) AS T ,

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* parts.bulk_qty AS Total_Cost_Price1, SUM( x.price * x.goods_qty ) / SUM( x.goo' at line 7

Comment: You have two `where` in your main query: `WHERE parts.bulk_qty >0 AND WHERE id IN`. And `select * ` in the subquery is no good style, better use something like `SELECT id`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT parts.product_code AS PC,SUM( x.goods_qty ) AS Qty, SUM( x.price * x.goods_qty ) / SUM( x.goods_qty ) AS Avg_Cost, parts.cost_price AS Avg_Cost1, parts.cost_price * parts.bulk_qty AS Total_Cost_Price1, SUM( x.price * x.goods_qty ) / SUM( x.goods_qty ) * parts.bulk_qty AS Total_Cost_Price, parts.sales_price * parts.bulk_qty AS Total_Sales_Price
FROM parts
LEFT JOIN received_goods_details x ON x.part_id = parts.id
LEFT JOIN invoice_details ON invoice_details.part_id = parts.id
WHERE parts.bulk_qty >0    AND id IN
(SELECT * 
FROM  `received_goods_details` 
WHERE part_id = parts.id
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 5) GROUP BY parts.id  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Remove second time where.

Comment: hi, i tried u r answer. Now i get an error like this  #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Ok great and second one is where also.

Comment: sorry i didn't get u.

Comment: Remove where before " id IN".

Comment: so what about parts.bulk_qty >0 can u please update ur answer

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93969/discussion-between-ajith-n-and-kaushik-maheta).